# How to use ACL plugin?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, acl

I am trying to use `ACL plugin` in my grails application. Based on the example given in this tutorial, http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/guide/3.%20Tutorial.html I need to create a `Service` that will implement the annotations `@PreAuthorize, @PostAuthorize, @PreFilter, and @PostFilter`.

I wanted to implement this approach in my controllers, instead of creating services. I have tried using the `@PreAuthorize` at the top of my action, but it returns an error message:

```
Annotation @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize is not allowed on element FIELD
```

Does this mean, `@PreAuthorize` annotation is not appropriate to call on each action in the controller?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't work on controllers, only on services (and other Spring beans). It might work on methods in 2.0 controllers since controllers are Spring beans, but I haven't tried it.

The problem is that Spring Security knows nothing about closures since they're a Groovy concept. They're invoked to handle web requests by Grails, but can't be intercepted by Spring since it only works with methods.

This is related to the issue of transactional services and closures. You cannot define a closure in a service and have it be transactional since Spring doesn't see it. Groovy lets you call closures as if they were methods but it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thank you so much! So this means that I have no choice but to create a service for each controller in order for me to use the ACL plugin. I have one more question, Is there an alternative way of assigning permissions on each action aside from using the ACL plugin? thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need a 1-1 between controller and service; you might be able to put everything in one service since the logic is similar, but certainly a few would suffice.

Comment: thank you so much..is it possible that instead of creating services for me to use the mentioned annotations, I will just convert the actions in my controllers into methods?would that be a logical approach?

Comment: can you please post an example implementing that approach?it would be a very great help especially for those who are still new in groovy. Please consider. Thank you so much!